# Lodash - Remove nested property from object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[{
    createdAt: "a date",
    id: "my id",
    registered: {
        __type: 'Date',
        iso: 'the date'
    }
}]
```

Because the field registered is an object and what i really just need is the `iso` field, there is a fast way in Lodash (or.... in javascript) to transform this array of object in another like this ?

```
[{
    createdAt: "a date",
    id: "my id",
    registered: 'the date'
}]
```

I did tried something like this... but do not works...

```
const newObj = _.values(measurements).map(element => {
    _.omit(element.registered['__type'])
});
```

Comment: `element.registered = element.registered.iso; return element`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind mutating the existing object, `.forEach` is all you need. Simply override that property, there is no need to delete anything:

```
arr.forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.registered = obj.registered.iso;
});
```

Comment: The simplest solution is even the correct answer... dont know why i was thinking was difficult.... is pretty easy!

Answer (score 2):

```
_.map(data,function(d){
  var iso=d.registered.iso
  d.registered=iso;
  return d;
})
```

This can help.